# React.JS component will not render my unordered list

Tags: reactjs, fetch-api

The following code represents the content I am currently rendering. While everything is rendering flawlessly, there is a single React component named `<GetCarInfo/>` that requires attention. Its purpose is to retrieve and display an unordered list from my custom API.

```
return (
        <div>
            <main>
            <MainTitle>data</MainTitle>
            
            <ul>
            <EntityTitle /*onSelect will also be passed into EntityTitle*/onSelect={() => handleClick('General Stuff')}/* This allows us to pass data into the parameters */>
                General    
            </EntityTitle>

            <EntityTitle /*onSelect will also be passed into EntityTitle*/onSelect={() => handleClick('Battery')}/* This allows us to pass data into the parameters */>
                Battery    
            </EntityTitle>
            </ul>

            <GetCarInfo/>

            <p>{selectedTopic}</p>
            <div id="car-content">
                <h3></h3>
                <p></p>
                <pre>
                    <code>

                    </code>
                </pre>
            </div>
            </main>
        </div>


    )
```

This is my GetCarInfo component:

```
function GetCarInfo(){
    const [info, setInfo] = useState([])
    var arrTitle = [];
    var obj;
    useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchInfo(){
            const response = await  fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/cars');
            var resData = await response.json();
            obj = JSON.parse(resData);
            setInfo(obj);
            for(var key in obj){
                arrTitle.push(key);
            }
           // console.log("This is resData", info);
        }
        fetchInfo();
    }, [])
    
    console.log(arrTitle);
    
    return (
        <>
            <ul>
                {arrTitle.map((title) => (
                    <li key={title}>{title}</li>
                ))}
            </ul>
        </>
    )
}
```

So, I fetch to a certain API and then within that API I push all the keys into an array called arrTitle. It does push the data it into the arrTitle. Then from thinking that it has pushed all the information into arrTitle I decide to return this component into my other component so it can get renderd the array.

I will post the API below but, I will have to block certain information for privacy reasons. So, arrTitle is supposed to be the strings that are underlined.

[image]

I suspect my component is running asynchronously, especially given that `fetch` is inherently asynchronous. To investigate, I used the browser console and noticed that the return component is executed before the array is populated, causing no data to display on the page.

It seems odd to me that even though I declared the array outside the function, it remains empty when accessed within the `GetCarItem` function. Any insights on why this might be happening?

[image]

I made progress by using `setInfo(arrTitle)` to successfully output titles to the console twice, which resolved most of the errors and warnings. Below is an updated code block of the improved component that allows the console log to function properly. Despite these positive developments, I've encountered an issue where the component is not rendering, even after trying methods like `JSON.stringify`. Any insights on how to address this rendering issue?

```
function GetCarInfo(){
    const [info, setInfo] = useState([])
    var arrTitle = [];
    var obj;
    useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchInfo(){
            const response = await  fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/cars');
            var resData = await response.json();
            obj = JSON.parse(resData);
            for(var key in obj){
                arrTitle.push(key);
            }
            setInfo(arrTitle); //This is the new thing I added
           // console.log("This is resData", info);
        }
        fetchInfo();
    }, [])

    console.log(info);
    return (
        <>
            <ul>
                {arrTitle.map((title) => (
                    <li key={title}>{title}</li>
                ))}
            </ul>
        </>
    )
}
```

[**Note**: I've observed a recurring occurrence where console logging inside another component happens twice. If anyone has insights into the reason behind this behavior, I'd appreciate the information as I'm curious to understand the underlying cause.][image]

I've done this on vanilla javascrip. Here is an image of how I want the data to prompt out.

[image]

However it prompts out like this. Don't mind the random buttons right now because I was testing something.

[image]

I've successfully resolved the issue by employing a specific approach. For anyone who, like me, is relatively new and faced challenges in prompting data onto the webpage, utilizing the current state from the 2D array, named `info`, proved to be the solution—thank goodness!

Despite the success, I'm still curious about the initial problem that prevented the data from displaying. Any insights into the root cause would be greatly appreciated. The code below is the code updated.

```
   const [info, setInfo] = useState([])
    var arrTitle = [];
    var obj;
    useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchInfo(){
            const response = await  fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/cars');
            var resData = await response.json();
            obj = JSON.parse(resData);
            for(var key in obj){
                arrTitle.push(key);     //ERROR: try stringfying the key before inserting it    
            }
            setInfo(arrTitle);
           // console.log("This is resData", info);
        }
        fetchInfo();
    }, [])

    console.log(info);
    return (
        <>
            <ul>
                {info.map((title) => (
                    <li key={title}>{title}</li>
                ))}
            </ul>
        </>
    )
}
```

[image]

Comment: I ended up fixing the issue. All I did was use my current state (info) in my 2d array. I mapped that instead and it fixed the issue to display the data correctly from my API as I wanted only keys. Anyways can anyone still tell me why it was not working in the first place?

Comment: You need to read a lot more about react I'm afraid. Everything you describe as odd is exactly how a react application behaves. You need to read about useEffect, and what the dependency array is. You need to read about useState and how changing the state triggers re-renders.

Comment: @flq I appreciate your guidance in pointing me towards the areas I need to explore. I'll delve into understanding useCase and useState, thanks once more! By the way, do you have any book recommendations for React? Currently, I've been relying on the React Documentation and a React course on Udemy.

Comment: The new react docs do a pretty good job I think. If you want to dive deeper, you can have a look at Kent C. dodds‘ epic react stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered an issue with infinite re-rendering in my React component. After making a specific adjustment, the problem was resolved. The issue stemmed from my getCars function being defined separately from the component, preventing it from triggering continuous re-renders. By moving this function outside the component, it was created only once and not tied to the component's re-rendering cycle.

```
    import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

// Extracted this from my component because
// this run once.
const getCars = async () => {
  const response = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/cars");
  var resData = await response.json();
  return resData;
};

export default function Car() {
  const [carObj, setCarObj] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    getCars().then(setCarObj);
  }, []);

  return (<h1>Data</h1>);
}
```

The modified code above demonstrates the getCars function fetching data from an API, decoupled from the Car component. Within the component, I utilized the useState and useEffect hooks to manage state and side effects. The useEffect hook, with an empty dependency array ([]), executed getCars once during the component's mount phase, updating the state with fetched data using setCarObj.

This change effectively resolved the infinite re-rendering issue. I found a helpful video (link provided) that guided me in understanding how separating functions from components can prevent re-rendering problems in React applications.